# C++ dyld: Library not loaded - after setting '-L'

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, g++, clang++

I'm currently working on a simple C++ project, but my situation is sligtly more complicated.
I'm using OpenCV library which I moved into folder next to my source code and referenced it from Makefile the same way as `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` but just changed paths to be relative to the folder that I want to pass together with source code.

The problem is that after running my Makefile

```
CC = clang++
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -g -Wall
SRCS = DisplayImage.cpp
PROG = DisplayImage

OPENCV = -I opencv/include/opencv4/opencv -I opencv/include/opencv4 -L opencv/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_quality -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
LIBS = $(OPENCV)

$(PROG):$(SRCS)
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(SRCS) $(LIBS)
```

Where I set `-L` flag.
`make` command works smoothly. But after invoking `./DisplayImage` I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_gapi.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Downloads/Display_Image3/./DisplayImage
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Where the most important part is this path `/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_gapi.4.2.dylib` which is from my understanding default path for libraries. I tried setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH``` but it did not work as well and gave me the same error.

Please note that I need to call the library from specified folder. Thank you.

**EDIT 19/03/20**

To describe more my situation.  I created a program on computer **A** with OpenCV installed but I need to run that program to computer where OpenCV is not installed. So on computer **A** I was building that program with following command:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -o DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp -g -v $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4)
```

I grabbed OpenCV library from folder that `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` was pointing at, moved it next to my code and moved whole 'repository' to the second computer where I try to build the same program with command:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="opencv/lib:$$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" #setting DYLD_FALLBACK_LIB_PATH
clang++ -std=c++17 -g -Wall -o DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp -I opencv/include/opencv4/opencv -I opencv/include/opencv4 -L opencv/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_quality -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
#running basically the same command, only replaced $(pkg-config....) with the exact ouput on computer A
```

After doing this, program builds with no problem, but when I try to run it, previous error that wais pointing to some opencv library has gone, but new one occured

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/tbb/lib/libtbb.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Downloads/Display_Image3/opencv/lib/libopencv_gapi.4.2.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

And that's weird because `echo $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` prints as excepted `opencv/lib:1163DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`

So should I now move more libraries from coputer **A**? Can I somehow find all of those libraries that are referenced? 
Or is there any better solution to this whole situation instead of forcing user to manually install opencv library?

Comment: I only get this when `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't set. You need to set it to the full path where the library exists. Also, you should consider setting `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` instead.

Comment: `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/:${DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH}"`

Comment: Hi @Mihir , thank you for your response. Sadly ```export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/:${DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH}"``` shouts at me because of recoursive variable. And after setting it just to for example ```/Users/name/Desktop```  like ```export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/name/Desktop"```doesn't work at all. :-( Could you please give me example how you're using it in Makefile?

Comment: it's a totally different story if you are doing it inside the Makefile. I am not an expert with Makefile` but will try to answer the same.

Comment: I see, no problem. How would you do that on command line? Because I’m a bit lost in this DYLD thing. You just co your ```clang++/g++ .... -o .... -I.... -L.... export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/:${DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH}"``` ?

Comment: On your main interactive shell, you need to issue this command, `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="<enter absolute path to libs here>:${DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH}"`. After that you should be able to execute your program

Answer (score 0):

As you told in the comments, you are setting `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` in `Makefile`. For that you would probably need to do something like this:

```
CC = clang++
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -g -Wall
SRCS = DisplayImage.cpp
PROG = DisplayImage

OPENCV = -I opencv/include/opencv4/opencv -I opencv/include/opencv4 -L opencv/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_quality -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
LIBS = $(OPENCV)

$(PROG):$(SRCS)
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(SRCS) $(LIBS) 

.PHONY: execute


execute: $(PROG)
     export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/:$$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" ; \
        $(PROG) $(USER_ARGS)
```

and then make it like:

```
make execute USER_FLAGS="enter you args here"
```

In makefile, every line in your recipes are executed with different shells.

For that reason, it's done like this:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/:$$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" ; \
        $(PROG) $(USER_ARGS)
```

to retain it in a single shell.

You can also achieve the same with [`.ONESHELL:`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html). Unfortunately I don't have that feature in my version of `Makefile`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed answer. Sadly, the issues still retains. Even when setting the path that needs to be used ```export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$(shell pwd)/opencv/lib:$$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" ; \``` or ```export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="opencv/lib:$$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" ; \``` :-/

Comment: @Michal, did you try exporting on command line and then running manually?

Comment: Sadly doens't work as well, @Mihir. It seems to pass all OpenCV library errors, but there is somewhere something still referenced to the /urs/local/opt library :-/ ```dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/tbb/lib/libtbb.dylib 
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Downloads/Display_Image3/opencv/lib/libopencv_gapi.4.2.0.dylib 
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```    But I seems to pass all the OpenCV lib errors. Sorry for the errour output to be on one line, it doens't let me to new-line it.

Comment: @Michal, can you show exactly what steps you did in your question. Maybe if there is some mistake, we can point it out?

Comment: @Michal, can you tell me the output of `echo $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH `

Comment: I edited my question, hope it's not too exhausting, but I tried to describe my situation as clearly as possible

Comment: @Michal, well no issues with me, ask without hesitation. As per your updation, you don't need to use `$$` when on command line. `$$` is to be used in Makefile only.

Comment: @Michal, also you need to give absolute path for your lib location. You can do it like this `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="<path_from_root>/opencv/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"`.